# Windows not maximizing correctly, Conky suspected

Tags: 14.04, unity, window, conky, maximized

Any program that I open is disregarding both the launcher and the panel when maximized. Attached are screenshots of `firefox`,

[image: Firefox] `gedit`,

[image: Text Editor] and `gnome-terminal` after typing `ls /`.

[image: Terminal]

I have had Conky installed for some time, and I recently changed `.conkyrc` to force Conky to draw as a panel window. Would this affect anything?

UPDATE: No programs are experiencing this problem when Conky is not running. I am now certain Conky is the culprit, but how do I keep Conky on the desktop without breaking maximization? (As a side note, in most modes Conky disappears when I either click on the desktop or press the "Show Desktop" shortcut.

Comment: Almost every DE has different conky settings to make it work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution. In `.conkyrc`, `own_window` must be set to `yes` and `own_window_type` must be `dock`. I cannot explain why this works, but there are no problems with windows, and Conky stays on the desktop when I interact with icons there.